# Can't receive PubNub message unless I publish a message first

Tags: ios, swift, pubnub

In my Swift application, I instantiate PubNub on viewDidLoad with the
correct configuration and then join a channel. However, it looks as if it
doesn't join the channel at all unless I fire the Send button action to
send a message (I threw the config/join channel code in the Send button
just to see if it would work). The code in the Send button function is
identical to the code in the viewDidLoad, but the code in viewDidLoad is
still ignored. This is frustrating because the current user on my app won't
receive messages sent to the channel unless the user first sends a message.

Here's the code in the view controller (I removed a lot of the code so it's easier to look at. If you think the issue lies elsewhere I can post more):

```
class MessageViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, PNObjectEventListener{

    var pubNub: PubNub!

    var pnConfiguration: PNConfiguration!

    var ids: String = ""

@IBAction func sendButton(sender: UIButton) {

        //create Pubnub channel
        pnConfiguration = PNConfiguration(publishKey: "key", subscribeKey: "key")
        pnConfiguration.uuid = currentUser.objectId!
        print(pnConfiguration.uuid)
        pubNub = PubNub.clientWithConfiguration(pnConfiguration)
        let channelName = ids as String
        let channelArray: [String] = [channelName]
        pubNub.subscribeToChannels(channelArray, withPresence: true)
        pubNub.publish(self.messageText.text!, toChannel: channelName, compressed: false, withCompletion: nil)
        pubNub.addListener(self)
        self.messageText.enabled = true
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.messageText.text = ""
            self.messageTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Query that sets self.ids = user1.objectId! + user2.objectId!

        //set Pubnub config
        pnConfiguration = PNConfiguration(publishKey: "key", subscribeKey: "key")
        pubNub = PubNub.clientWithConfiguration(pnConfiguration)
        pnConfiguration.uuid = currentUser.objectId!
        //create channel
        let channelName = ids as String
        print(channelName)
        let channelArray: [String] = [channelName]
        pubNub.subscribeToChannels(channelArray, withPresence: true)
        pubNub.addListener(self)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.messageTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

After looking at the logs it looks like the reason why it's not working is because it's joining a channel called "", even though the `print(channelName)` returns the real channel name. Why isn't it taking the channel name? Is it not the right data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet I don't see any place where you set real value for *ids* variable which you declare at line **#7**. So client use value which is stored in that variable: **""**
I think this variable changed during controller life-cycle and set to proper value before you hit *sendButton* but not available at time when view is loaded.

Best regards,
Sergey

Comment: Thanks for the help! This got me on the right track. For some reason, the Pubnub client was initializing before my ids were being set in a Parse query. I moved the init code to a separate function and now call the function immediately after the ids are created. That part works now. For some reason though, my message UUID isn't being set correctly. It's ignoring my ` pnConfiguration.uuid` code. It prints the correct UUID, but when I actually send a message, the message.uuid in the client function returns a very different value

Comment: Is there a different method I have to use to set the message uuid? Other than the ` pnConfiguration.uuid` code?

Comment: @james that _uuid_ is for debug purposes and give information about receiver client itself. If you need to make remote message receivers aware of user UUID - you need to send it as part of message payload.

Comment: How would I do that? Is there a specific publish method that allows you to set uuid?

Comment: @james no, you just publish dictionary for instance: `@{@"message":@"my message",@"senderID":@"john doe"}`. On receiver side you check _senderID_ from received message and work with it.